# iPhone connects to WiFi but drops Internet connection

Tags: iphone, wifi, network

I am able to connect to WiFi alright, but the Internet connection drops off after about 60 seconds.

In the routers console, the assigned IP address is shown which matches with one on the device.

In the current connections list in routers, the iPhone is listed.

After 60 seconds of connection to the WiFi, when the Internet connectivity drops off, the IP address in the connections list in the router for the iPhone changes to `192.2.28.112` and the host name changes to `Static IP`. I am unsure why this is happening. The mac address for the listed item matches with that of my iPhone.

All the iPhone network settings are at default. I have tried restarting the device and resetting network settings on both the router and the iPhone.

The model is an iPhone 6. I have had this problem ever since the day I bought it. I have faced similar issue with one of my friends computer. All the other devices never face any issues with the WiFi.

Current router settings matched with the one recommended by Apple. There are no special items such as MAC filters enabled in the router.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is an iPhone 6? What version of iOS are you running? Lastly, have you contacted Apple Support about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is abnormal behaviour, and therefore probably a bug in either your wireless router or iOS, more likely your router. It seems to assign your iPhone a static IP after some time for no visible reason (although you haven't used a setting to tell your router to do that).

A list of what you should try, try one after another if it still does not work:

1. Check for firmware updates for your wireless router. That rules out any known issue to the manufacturer, where fixes are already available.
2. Reset your wireless router to factory defaults, as that rules out any issues with configuration (intended or unintended).
3. Tell your iPhone to "forget" your wireless network, and connect to it again, supplying the password. That way, you're ruling out any issues with configuration files with your particular network.
4. Make an encrypted backup of your iPhone using iTunes if you want to be able to rollback any of the following changes.
5. Reset your iPhone's network settings (In Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings). You'll have to reconnect to all wireless networks again, as it also deletes passwords, but it makes sure that no issues exist in configuration files regarding general network configuration.
6. Do a factory restore on your iPhone. If it works now, try restoring the backup and check if the issue is still fixed.
7. If it still does not help, you might consider calling Apple support (although there is not much more they can do).

Comment: Also can other devices (especially mobile devices) hold a signal for longer than 60 seconds? If they can't its a networking issue.